# SSH conection: terminal works but Nautilus does not

Tags: networking, ssh

I used to browse the files in a remote server using **connect to server** option in file managers like Nautilus and Thunar by entering `sftp://user@server`, but it does not work anymore. Strange thing is I can still connect tho that server using

```
ssh user@server
```

command in the terminal. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

I had lines in the original `$HOME/.bashrc` file that changed the `HOME` environment variable and then sourced another `.bashrc` file in that new `HOME` directory. After eliminating this code, I do not know why but, problem solved.